# R - break character vector of i comma-separated IDs into i discrete vectors of a data frame

Tags: r, regex, string, vector, data-cleaning

data frame `df` includes two character vectors. Here are the first 10 rows:

```
rowid  codes_raw                            
a      15-1132, 15-1133                     
b      21-1091, 21-1094, 21-1099            
c      25-9011, 25-9021, 25-9031, 25-9099   
d      31-9093, 31-9099                     
e      33-9092, 33-9099                     
f      37-2011, 37-2019                     
g      39-4011, 39-4021                     
h      47-5051, 47-5099                     
i      49-2094, 49-2095                     
j      49-9041
```

`df$codes_raw` contains 1 to i discrete identifiers for a given row. These identifiers need to be spread across i new vectors in the same data frame. The result should look like this:

```
rowid codes_raw                            code_1     code_2     code_3     code_4
a     15-1132, 15-1133                     15-1132    15-1133
b     21-1091, 21-1094, 21-1099            21-1091    21-1094    21-1099
c     25-9011, 25-9021, 25-9031, 25-9099   25-9011    25-9021    25-9031    25-9099
d     31-9093, 31-9099                     31-9093    31-9099
e     33-9092, 33-9099                     33-9092    33-9099
f     37-2011, 37-2019                     37-2011    37-2019
g     39-4011, 39-4021                     39-4011    39-4021
h     47-5051, 47-5099                     47-5051    47-5099
i     49-2094, 49-2095                     49-2094    49-2095
j     49-9041                              49-9041
```

My current solution involves a separate `if_else()` call for each piece of the string, which is clunky. For example:

```
df$code_2 <- if_else(
  grepl(',', df$codes_raw),
  sub('.*,\\s*', '', df$codes_raw),
  ' ')
```

I also want the solution to work in cases where I have as many as 20 commas in `df$codes_raw`. I'm seeking more elegant and dynamic alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'separate()'

```
library(tidyr)

lengths <- max(sapply(strsplit(df$codes_raw, split= ", "), length)) 
names  <- sapply(seq(lengths), function(x) paste0("code_", x))

df %>%
  separate(codes_raw,
           into = names, sep = ", " , remove = FALSE)

   rowid                       codes_raw  code_1  code_2  code_3  code_4
1      a                 15-1132,15-1133 15-1132 15-1133    <NA>    <NA>
2      b         21-1091,21-1094,21-1099 21-1091 21-1094 21-1099    <NA>
3      c 25-9011,25-9021,25-9031,25-9099 25-9011 25-9021 25-9031 25-9099
4      d                 31-9093,31-9099 31-9093 31-9099    <NA>    <NA>
5      e                 33-9092,33-9099 33-9092 33-9099    <NA>    <NA>
6      f                 37-2011,37-2019 37-2011 37-2019    <NA>    <NA>
7      g                 39-4011,39-4021 39-4011 39-4021    <NA>    <NA>
8      h                 47-5051,47-5099 47-5051 47-5099    <NA>    <NA>
9      i                 49-2094,49-2095 49-2094 49-2095    <NA>    <NA>
10     j                         49-9041 49-9041    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: this solution works well but (a) requires manual specification of the number of `into` vars, and (b) produces a series of warnings because of the NA values for the `into` vectors. `suppressWarnings()` wrapper obviously solves, but introduces an obvious concern if the original data frame is updated

Comment: You can set argument ‘extra’ to do what you want. See the documentation

Comment: What if the number of columns into which these values have to be split is not known? Dynamic naming I'd therefore suggested

Answer (score 2):

to automate entering column names, I suggest doing this

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(codes_raw, sep = ", ") %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  mutate(id_cols = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(rowid, names_from = id_cols, values_from = codes_raw, names_prefix = "code_") %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 5
   rowid code_1  code_2  code_3  code_4 
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 a     15-1132 15-1133 NA      NA     
 2 b     21-1091 21-1094 21-1099 NA     
 3 c     25-9011 25-9021 25-9031 25-9099
 4 d     31-9093 31-9099 NA      NA     
 5 e     33-9092 33-9099 NA      NA     
 6 f     37-2011 37-2019 NA      NA     
 7 g     39-4011 39-4021 NA      NA     
 8 h     47-5051 47-5099 NA      NA     
 9 i     49-2094 49-2095 NA      NA     
10 j     49-9041 NA      NA      NA
```

or

```
nm <- paste0("code_", seq_len(max(str_count(df$codes_raw, pattern = ",")) + 1))

df %>% 
  separate(
    codes_raw, 
    into = nm, 
    sep = ", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You say the maximum amount of columns is 20, so there is a way to do that with regex containing capturing groups (using `library(namedCapture)`) like

```r
rowid <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
codes_raw <- c("15-1132, 15-1133", "21-1091, 21-1094, 21-1099", "25-9011, 25-9021, 25-9031, 25-9099", "31-9093, 31-9099", "49-9041")
df <- data.frame(rowid, codes_raw)

library(namedCapture)
n = 20                              # Max number of columns
pattern <- "^(?P<code_1>\\d+-\\d+)" # Pattern start
for (x in 2:n) {                    # Add more optional columns
  pattern <- paste0(pattern, "(?:\\s*,\\s*(?P<code_",x,">\\d+-\\d+))?")
}
pattern <- paste0(pattern,"$")      # End of string anchor added
df1 <- str_match_named(df$codes_raw, pattern)  # Extract column data
df1 <- df1[, colSums(df1 != "") != 0] # Remove empty columns
df1 <- cbind(rowid, df1)              # Put back the rowid column
```

Output:

```r
> cbind(rowid, df1)
     rowid code_1    code_2    code_3    code_4   
[1,] "a"   "15-1132" "15-1133" ""        ""       
[2,] "b"   "21-1091" "21-1094" "21-1099" ""       
[3,] "c"   "25-9011" "25-9021" "25-9031" "25-9099"
[4,] "d"   "31-9093" "31-9099" ""        ""       
[5,] "e"   "49-9041" ""        ""        ""
```

Here is [a sample regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fnkcpm/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<code_1>\d+-\d+)` - a named capturing group with `code_1` names matching one or more digits, `-` and one or more digits
- `(?:\s*,\s*(?P<code_2>\d+-\d+))?` - an optional sequence of a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespace and then Group "code_2" that matches 1+ digits, `-`, 1+ digits and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Do it dynamically (creation of column names) like this.  This will work for any number of strings concatenated together

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'rowid  codes_raw                            
a      "15-1132, 15-1133"                     
b      "21-1091, 21-1094, 21-1099"            
c      "25-9011, 25-9021, 25-9031, 25-9099"   
d      "31-9093, 31-9099"                     
e      "33-9092, 33-9099"                     
f      "37-2011, 37-2019"                     
g      "39-4011, 39-4021"                     
h      "47-5051, 47-5099"                     
i      "49-2094, 49-2095"                     
j      49-9041', header = T)
df
#>    rowid                          codes_raw
#> 1      a                   15-1132, 15-1133
#> 2      b          21-1091, 21-1094, 21-1099
#> 3      c 25-9011, 25-9021, 25-9031, 25-9099
#> 4      d                   31-9093, 31-9099
#> 5      e                   33-9092, 33-9099
#> 6      f                   37-2011, 37-2019
#> 7      g                   39-4011, 39-4021
#> 8      h                   47-5051, 47-5099
#> 9      i                   49-2094, 49-2095
#> 10     j                            49-9041

library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% separate(codes_raw, into = paste0('code_', seq_len(1 + max(str_count(df$codes_raw, ', ')))), 
                remove = F, sep = ', ')
#> Warning: Expected 4 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 9 rows [1, 2, 4,
#> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].
#>    rowid                          codes_raw  code_1  code_2  code_3  code_4
#> 1      a                   15-1132, 15-1133 15-1132 15-1133    <NA>    <NA>
#> 2      b          21-1091, 21-1094, 21-1099 21-1091 21-1094 21-1099    <NA>
#> 3      c 25-9011, 25-9021, 25-9031, 25-9099 25-9011 25-9021 25-9031 25-9099
#> 4      d                   31-9093, 31-9099 31-9093 31-9099    <NA>    <NA>
#> 5      e                   33-9092, 33-9099 33-9092 33-9099    <NA>    <NA>
#> 6      f                   37-2011, 37-2019 37-2011 37-2019    <NA>    <NA>
#> 7      g                   39-4011, 39-4021 39-4011 39-4021    <NA>    <NA>
#> 8      h                   47-5051, 47-5099 47-5051 47-5099    <NA>    <NA>
#> 9      i                   49-2094, 49-2095 49-2094 49-2095    <NA>    <NA>
#> 10     j                            49-9041 49-9041    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_split()` from the `stringr` library to split codes in a list, and then convert list of vectors (of unequal length) into a matrix, and then use `mutate()` to join to your original dataframe. Here is an example:

```
#your example data
df<-data.frame(rowid = c("a","b", "c","d", "e", "f","g","h","i","j"),
               codes_raw = c("15-1132, 15-1133", "21-1091, 21-1094, 21-1099" ,"25-9011, 25-9021, 25-9031, 25-9099","31-9093, 31-9099", "33-9092, 33-9099",                     
        "37-2011, 37-2019","39-4011, 39-4021", "47-5051, 47-5099", "49-2094, 49-2095","49-9041"))

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
#Split codes raw by comma
l<-str_split(df$codes_raw, ",")
#get length of each code
n.codes <- sapply(l, length)
#find the longest number of codes, and make a sequence from 1 to that number.
seq.max <- seq_len(max(n.codes))
#Fill NAs in blanks as you make a matrix. Convert to dataframe.
codes_in_columns <- t(sapply(l, "[", i = seq.max)) %>% 
  data.frame(.)
#Set the desired column names.
names(codes_in_columns)<- paste0("code_",seq.max)
#combine original with separated codes
df<-df %>% mutate(codes_in_columns )
```